# BigQuery stored procedure: delete when id in CTE

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I need to write a procedure to delete id that already exists in my table K and insert the newest one. But I write my CTE after the insert part like below:

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `Update_K`(target_date DATE)
OPTIONS (strict_mode=true)
BEGIN
DECLARE  StartDate DATETIME default DATE_ADD(  target_date)  ;

do delete from  K where ID in (SELECT ID FROM CTE) ;

INSERT INTO K
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
       ID
       ,EventID
       , SN
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobID, case when EventID='1' then 'Y' else 'N' end 
ORDER BY SN DESC) AS SortId
  FROM JE
  where JE.EventID in ('1','2') and DATE(eTime)= StartDate
  ) g where SortId=1
 )
 SELECT 
  M.ID,
.
.
.
.
.
.
FROM M
Left Join CTE
on M.ID=CTE.ID
```

It does not seem to work. Should I alter it like this instead? Or is there any better way to write this?

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `Update_K`(target_date DATE)
OPTIONS (strict_mode=true)
BEGIN

do delete from  K where ID in (SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT 
       ID
       ,EventID
       , SN
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobID, case when EventID='1' then 'Y' else 'N' end 
ORDER BY SN DESC) AS SortId
  FROM JE
  where JE.EventID in ('1','2') and DATE(eTime)= StartDate
  ) g where SortId=1
)) ;

INSERT INTO K
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
       ID
       ,EventID
       , SN
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobID, case when EventID='1' then 'Y' else 'N' end 
ORDER BY SN DESC) AS SortId
  FROM JE
  where JE.EventID in ('1','2') and DATE(eTime)= current_date()
  ) g where SortId=1
 )
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Are you facing any error messages when executing the first code?